# AWS Lambda | FTP Connector | Is there any specific setting in AWS lambda that needs to modified to connect it to external FTP sources?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ftp

We have a requirement to build a framework that pulls files from FTP and can place it over S3. We are using lambda function to achieve the same and python as the language. Unfortunately the same piece of code which is able to connect to connect to FTP from local machine's complier is not working on AWS lambda and entering into except block. Below is the code-

```py
def open_ftp_connection(ftp_host, ftp_port, ftp_username, ftp_password): 
  client = paramiko.SSHClient()
  client.load_system_host_keys() 
  try: 
    transport = paramiko.Transport(ftp_host, ftp_port) 
  except Exception as e: 
    return 'conn_error'
  try: 
    transport.connect(username=ftp_username, password.ftp_password)
  except Exception as identifier: 
    return 'auth_error' 
  ftp_connection = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport) 
  return ftp_connection
```

Although the host name and port number are correct, It is entering into except block and returning 'conn error'. The same code is able to connect to FTP from local machine. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your AWS Lambda function currently configured to connect to a VPC? If so, it probably does not have Internet access. Try disconnecting it from the VPC.

Comment: Hi John - Thanks for the reply. I have checked our lambda function and it is not configured with any VPC. "This function isn't connected to a VPC." -> This is the message displayed. As our lambda is not connected to any VPC so, it should be able to connect to our FTP right? Can you please comment?

Comment: What makes you think that `load_system_host_keys()` is working as expected? The [documentation](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/paramiko.SSHClient.load_system_host_keys) says that if no filename is provided "an attempt will be made to read keys from the user's local 'known hosts' file". Have you somehow created that file in the AWS Lambda environment? I know nothing about Paramiko, but that might be a start, since the error is occurring before it tries to connect. Why are you using an SSHClient for an FTP connection?  I hope you know what your code is meant to be doing.